# Syntax error on line 164 Apache24/conf/httpd.conf Cannot load modules/mod_rewrite.so into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: apache-http-server, http, window, redirection, web

I am trying to run Apache using httpd.exe under command prompt administration privileges, but it pops up with the error message stated above does anyone know a solution?

I am expecting a solution to the problem I am having.
(Im on windows 11)

Comment: Have you added `RewriteEngine on` before your rewrite directives? Is the module installed (see [link](https://serverfault.com/a/265295/18736))?

Comment: I don’t believe I installed it I simply removed the comment, how do I install it? And yes, I did it before my rewrite directives.

Comment: Windows does not use *.so* files. Where did you get Apache Httpd for Windows from?

Comment: @DanielB: Apache takes care of the `.so` convention on Windows, see [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_so.html).

Comment: @Lukar: How have you installed Apache on Windows, and why don't you use IIS?

Comment: I didnt use IIS because I havent heard of it and I was following this article https://www.semrush.com/blog/301-redirect-htaccess/

Comment: Daniel, I installed Apache using this third party website https://www.apachelounge.com/download/

Comment: I followed the link that you showed me Harry, but unfortunately, it came up with the following error messages 
"The system cannot find the path specified"
"'a2enmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
"'LoadModule' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.